# Keep a specific activity alive while switching between Activities

Tags: android, android-manifest, locationmanager

My application contains 6 separated activities, one of them returns GPS coordination, this activity work perfectly when it's open but first I return to the main activity it stops updating location.

details :
I have created a `GPS services` and called it in the `Manifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".Services.GPS_Service" />
```

This is the Service :

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {

    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        listener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                i.putExtra("Longitude", location.getLongitude());
                i.putExtra("Latitude", location.getLatitude());

                final Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
                final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

                i.putExtra("time", sdf.format(date));
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, listener);
    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (locationManager != null) {
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must create a foreground service to run in background. For more details click on below link. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your answers and the phrasing you use: "when it's open but first I return to the main activity" - I am assuming by 'I return to the main activity' you mean that either onBackPressed is involved, or just a simple finish() was called. For that reason, onDestroy was called so your listener gets cancelled, and that why it stops working.

Comment: Thank you richard, but is it the same thing/lifecycle with fragments ? I mean If I move from one fragment to another am I going to face the same behaviour?

Comment: it depends on the situation, but if the navigation is the same, yes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two activities active at the same time. You must use Android Service to update location.

Comment: Following the OP sample, the problem must be elsewhere. It is true that only one activity can be active at the same time, but a background activity would not stop receiving location updated unless the listener is cancelled in onPause/onStop.

Comment: Thank you for the time you gave to answer my question, but is it the same thing/lifecycle with fragments ? I mean If I move from one fragment to another am I going to face the same behaviour?